# How to save the object with assigned id

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

```
class User {
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    int id; 
}
User user1 = new User();
session.save(user1); //may be I can got user1.id = 10
User user2 = new User();
user2.id = 20;
session.save(user2); //The user2.id may be 11
```

How can I save user2 and the id is 20?

Comment: You are already setting it. What's your problem now ?

Comment: after session.save(user2) the id will change, may be the user2.id = 11

Comment: You want to save user1 without giving an ID. But the ID of user1 may be 20. And when you save user2 having ID 20, there will be an exception. So you do not want to get an exception? Do you want hibernate to change the ID of user1 when encontered such situtation?

Comment: I wanna save the user2 which id is 20, So after save(user2) the user2.id = 20, but actually it is not 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any such option available in hibernate. Instead of **AUTO**,you can try the following strategy options also:

**GenerationType.TABLE** - the persistence provider uses a database table for managing keys.

**GenerationType.SEQUENCE** - the persistence provider uses a databases sequence for key generation. The database must support Sequences

**GenerationType.IDENTITY** - the persistence provider defers to the database for key generation. The database must support the IDENTITY column type.

**Another point :** it will slow down the performance also. For each insert, it will have to search through whole ID column. You can imagine how much it will impact to performace.

Comment: I search many about it. May be the only way to assign the id  is remove GeneratedValue. But if I remove it. I cannot got the id after session.save.